# Form validation using Laravel framework

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2

I have a form containing two fields, one for **email address** and the other for **mobile number**, so the user can sign up for my site.

Users are required to fill out at least one of these two fields. How can I validate posted data from this form using **Laravel 5.2** `ValidatesRequests` trait in UserController? (as all controllers use `ValidatesRequests` trait in laravel 5.2)

Here is a sample but it forces user to fill both fields (whereas I'm only requiring them to fill out one of the two fields):

```
        $rules = [
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required'];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-required-without

```
$rules = [
    'mobile' => 'required_without:email',
    'email'  => 'required_without:mobile'
];

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```